# Integral on semicircular arc of a function with a simple pole at $z=0$

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, residue-calculus, laurent-series, meromorphic-functions

Let $C(\epsilon)$ denote the semicircular arc about $z=0$. Suppose $f(z)$ is a meromorphic function that has a simple pole at $z=0$. I'm trying to show that
$$\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\int_{C(\epsilon)} f(z) = -\pi i \mathrm{Res}_{z=0}(f(z))$$

First, I expand $f(z)$ as a Laurent series $f(z) = \frac{b_{1}}{z} + \sum_{k=0}^\infty a_kz^k$ and then I integrate about the specified region:
$$\int_{C(\epsilon)} f(z) = -\pi i b_1 + \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{a_k\epsilon^{k+1}}{k+1}(1+(-1)^k).$$

Now I need to justify that 
$$\lim_{\epsilon\to 0} \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{a_k\epsilon^{k+1}}{k+1}(1+(-1)^k)=0.$$
but I have an issue with interchanging the sum and the limit.
I was thinking of using the ratio test combined with the bound on $a_k$ provided by Taylor's Theorem, but is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not hard to show that sum tends to $0$ with $\epsilon$. But there's no reason it has to come up. Instead of starting with the Laurent series start with $b_{-1}/z + g(z)$, where $g$ is holomorphic near the origin, hence bounded in some neighborhood of the origin.

Comment: So I'd let $\epsilon$ be sufficiently small so that $g(z)$ is holomorphic inside $C(\epsilon)$, then by say, the maximum modulus principle, $|g(z)|\leq M$ for some $M$. So $$\left|\int_{C(\epsilon)} g(z) \right|\leq  M\pi \epsilon$$ and we're done?

Comment: @Rdrr More or less. If $C(\epsilon)$ is a semicircle there is no "inside $C(\epsilon)$. Nothing to do with maximum modulus here, all you need is what I said: $g$ is continuous at $0$, hence bounded in some neighborhood of $0$.